# Correct usage of sendgrid

Tags: smtp, sendgrid

I am using Python sendgrid library to send emails.
However, I am having some weird issues.

I created a template on Sendgrid, and am using that template id to send emails.

However in the python code, I need to:
1. Call set_subject(..), even if I do not want to modify the subject. I understand this is because <%subject%> must be present in the template. Is there a way I choose not to specify <%subject%> in the template and avoid the set_subject(parameters) function call? (Right now I call set_subject with an empty string.)

2. The same holds for set_text(..) as well. Again, this is because <%body%> must be present in the template. Is there any way to avoid adding <%body%> in the template and thus not have the set_text(parameters) function call? (Right now I call set_text with an empty string.)
3. I have a html-formatted email template. If I do not call set_html(..) function, then the email is sent as a text-only email without formatting. However, if I set_html("some styling") the email is sent with all the formatting. What is the use of setting the template if I need to call set_html(parameters) from the code anyways?

For reference following is the code I am using:

```
import sendgrid
def send_twitch_welcome_message(user_name, user_email, confirmation_url=None):        if not sg:
        return 500, 'SendGrid not configured'
    message = sendgrid.Mail()
    message.add_filter('templates', 'enable', '1')
    message.add_filter('templates', 'template_id',
            some_template_id)
    message.add_to(desired_email_idl)
    message.set_from(my_email_id)

    message.set_subject(' ')
    message.set_text(' ')
    message.set_html("""
        <h3 style="margin-bottom: 20px; font-size:18px; color:#000000;
        font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif; font-weight:normal;">
        Something !</h3>
        """) # This works fine, but commenting this function call leads to text-only email


    message.add_substitution('key', value)
    status, msg = sg.send(message)
    return status, msg
```

Comment: Can you ask the question at the SendGrid Python GitHub repo as well, so the library maintainer can take a look. https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/issues :)

Comment: Thanks @kunalbatra. I did that: https://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/python-api-issues